# Creating fileset based on list of directories in a dirset

Tags: file, ant, directory

How can I create a fileset in Ant that contains all the files existing in a number of directories that I have in a dirset? It seems as if fileset can only take one directory as input, not a set of directories.

Any input would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [files resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#files) is "equivalent to a fileset with no base directory". Perhaps you can use this type to fit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to combine dirsets and filesets by using the MultiRootFileSet which is available in Ant 1.9.4. The code below finds all files which terminate with ".xml" using the directories found in a dirset.

```
<dirset id="mydirset" dir="rootDirectory" />

<!-- combine all the directories in the dirset using a comma separator -->
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="dirs" refid="mydirset"/>

<multirootfileset basedirs="${dirs}" type="files">
    <include name="**/*.xml" />
</multirootfileset>
```